# How to add items to an ArrayList in Java directly from a file?

Tags: java, file, arraylist

This seems easy enough but i can't manage to do it, although i did this in C#.
For the sake of this example i'll keep it simple.
I have a `Person` class, with the fields `name` and `age`. I have constructors and getters and setters.

In my main class, i want to read data from a file and create a `Person` object that will be added to an `ArrayList`. Here is the part of the code that doesn't seem to work right. I used a Debugger and saw that the reading is correct, each line of my text file is at some point in the `p` variable, but when I print it only displays the last person in the file for x times (where x is the number of persons in file). I used the `i` variable because i looked online and saw that `.add` has overloads. First time I tried only `lst.add(p)` and second time I used the `i` variable in order to specify on which position `i` want my person to be in list.

```
File f = new File("fisier.txt");

    try{
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(f);
        int i = 0;
        while(scn.hasNext()){
            p.nume = scn.next();
            p.varsta = scn.nextInt();
            lst.add(i,p);
            i++;
        }
        scn.close();

    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(Persoana a : lst)
        System.out.println(a.nume + " " + a.varsta);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of `Person` in your loop:

```
while(scn.hasNext()) {
    String name = scn.next();
    int age = scn.nextInt();
    Person p = new Person(name, age);
    lst.add(p); // simply add to the end of the list
}
```

Comment: Ok. I tried now and it worked. I forgot i had to make a new person every time, now i feel bad for asking such a question. Thanks for the fast response.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the same object each time the `Scanner` read a new values, so you need to create a new `Person` object each time you able fetch new value.

**For Example**:

```
while(scn.hasNext()){
    int age = scn.next();
    String name = scn.nextInt();
    Person p = new Person(name, age);
    lst.add(p);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(scanner.hasNext()) 
{
  String name = scanner.next();
  int age = scanner.nextInt();
  Person person = new Person(name, age);
  list.add(person);
}
```

Create a instance of the Person.